# Possible to have independent observations without random sampling?

Tags: random-variable, independence, observational-study

Is some form of random sampling **required** for observations to meet the "independence" assumption of various types of regression analysis and hypothesis testing?

My data (fish counts, **without replacement** - i.e., didn't throw it back) was collected like this:

Sites for observation were selected based on a particular interest/purpose and each site has been repeatedly visited over time (with breaks in-between, so not continuous).

Does this "clustering" or "grouping" of the data at specific locations mean that each observation is not independent? Does it depend on what type of data is collected (a mobile vs. stationary target population)? Is this clustering of the data points (a non-random sampling method) all someone needs to know if they wish to determine if the data are independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First selecting a number of sites, and than collecting observations from those sites is a classic example of not independent samples. This is very common; most national surveys do that when they want to do in person interviews. If they do random sampling, then the interviewers need to travel all over the country. It is much more efficient to first select a few towns, and than sent an interviewer to each of these towns and do all the interviews in that town. But, when you do your analysis you will need to take that into account.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For my own understanding, the data collected "within" each site are not independent from each other or there's no independence between sites? Or both? The data at each site are too related because they all come from the same location and therefore may share too many similar characteristics; that commonality equates to being "not independently surveyed?"

Comment: Correct, two persons randomly drawn form the same town will on average be more similar on a lot of characteristics than two person randomly drawn from the entire population.